# Decrease credit for every Create and Update action in controller. Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

How can I decrease `@user.credit` every time `User` makes changes or updates in `Entity Controller`. I would have to make changes in `User` table from `Entity` controller to do this.

Purpose of this is that app charges money/credits for making actions in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need and `after_create` callback in the `Entity` model.

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  after_save :update_user_credits
  def update_user_credits
    User.update_counters user_id, credits: -1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to `bcd`'s answer, you'd be better changing the `user` associative object rather than invoking a totally new SQL call:

```
#app/models/entity.rb
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   after_save :update_credits

   private

   def update_credits
      self.user.decrement! :credit
   end
end
```

[Refs for the `decrement!` method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/decrement%21)

Comment: `decrement` is really bad for concurrency: it alters the loaded value from the DB and sends an update. The update_counters does an `UPDATE table SET counter = counter + 1`. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5d1402a1011f58b405e42007d3ceed4e122d273e/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L328 https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/232115a9eb3e8bc6c664c84913bfebdd2c54f007/activerecord/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb#L77

Comment: Point taken, than you for the references.